# How to get namespaces for xmpp server

Tags: xmpp, telnet, xml-namespaces

I know the xmpp server and port. And able connect via telnet.

However, when try to query for creating new user or authenticate (existing user), getting error as invalid namespace.

So how to know what are the namespace and XML tags to be used for a given any host.

Answer (score 1):

XML Namespaces aren't specific to an XMPP server. In general, all XMPP servers follow the same XMPP protocol and start by undergoing normal XMPP stream negotiation as specified by [`RFC 6120`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120). To see this in action, you can start this process by telneting to teh server and sending a new stream:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<stream:stream
    from='juliet@im.example.com'
    to='im.example.com'
    version='1.0'
    xml:lang='en'
    xmlns='jabber:client'
    xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>
```

(you'll need to substitute to/from for the appropriate address, of course). The XML namespaces in this start stream element (`jabber:client` and `http://etherx.jabber.org/streams`_ are used by all XMPP servers. The server should then respond with its own opening stream; from there you can complete stream negotiation as specified by the RFC.